# Angular 2. Как в корневом компоненте проверить, что дочерний компонент успешно загружен

Tags: angular2

Я бы хотел проверить в корневом компоненте `AppComponent`, загружен ли дочерний компонент. Под дочерним компонентом я понимаю тот компонент, который соответствует текущему URL, этот компонент загрузится в директиву `router-outlet` в шаблоне компонента AppComponent. В маршруте дочернего компонента есть асинхронный guard canActivate, он проверяет, можно перейти на данное состояние.

Я бы хотел выполнить свой код в компоненте AppComponent после того, как guard canActivate выполнится и дочерний компонент будет готов к показу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать использовать injected Router и следить за ним, для получения состояния?

```
class AppComponent{
   constructor(router: Router) {
    const state: RouterState = router.routerState;
    const root: ActivatedRoute = state.root;
    const child = root.firstChild;
    const id: Observable<string> = child.params.map(p => p.id);
    id.subscribe(id => checkforId(id));
  }
```